# IRS Free File Fillable forms -- "Done with this form" button grayed out for 1040

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, free-file-fillable-forms

I just used the Free File Fillable forms screen to do my 2015 taxes.  All went well except for one thing.  I could never successfully click on the "Done with this form" button for the 1040 as it is "grayed out".

This didn't keep me from submitting my tax forms, but I'm curious as to what is going on here.

Comment: Even software made by/for the IRS can have bugs. If you definitely filled everything out on the form, assuming it has validation, it's probably as simple as that.

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly from my last 4 years using FFFF (I finally switched to TurboTax this year), the "Done with this form" button is what you press to be taken back to the main screen (i.e. the 1040) after you're done working on any form/schedule that's not the 1040.  So I believe it's greyed out because pressing it wouldn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks, that's probably it.  A better designed system would have removed the button from the 1040 page instead of graying it out.

Comment: True, but I was always impressed at just how well FFFF works given that it's free and was made by the government.

Comment: FWIW, it is not made by the government - it is made by Intuit. FFFF is essentially TurboTax stripped of its question/answer interface.

Comment: And Intuit seems to have gone out of its way to make it hard to use- they only built FFF because they were required to offer a free  version when they got the ability to file electronically.

Answer (score -1):

This is mentioned NOWHERE on the page, but you must click on the "STEP 2. E-File Your Tax Forms" tab at the top of the form to proceed further.

Infuriating. ಠ_ಠ